# $\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)=X\setminus \operatorname{Int}(A)$

Tags: general-topology

$X$ is a space and $A$ is a subset.

If $A$ is open then $X\setminus A$ is closed and $\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)=X\setminus A$, though if $A$ is open then doesn't this make the questions trivial because then $A=\operatorname{Int}(A)$?

Then I know $\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)$ is $X\setminus A$ unioned with its limit points. I've tried to do subset inclusion in both directions, but there must be some main idea I'm missing here to not have gotten it in either direction.

One direction I went and got stuck on trying inclusion in the forward direction was that because $\operatorname{Int}(A) \subset A$, then $X\setminus A \subset X\setminus\operatorname{Int}(A)$. Then any epsilon neighborhood of any $x$ in $X$ intersects with $X\setminus \operatorname{Int}(A)$, but I don't see how to use that.

Comment: You cannot use epsilon neighborhoods unless your $X$ is a metric space.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\text{cl}(X\setminus A)$ is the smallest closed set which contains $X\setminus A$ and since $\text{Int}(A)$ is open, $X \setminus \text{Int}(A)$ is a closed set, and it contains $X \setminus A$ therefore by definition $\text{cl}(X\setminus A) \subset X \setminus \text{Int}(A)$.

Now, we would like to prove the reverse inclusion, $\text{cl}(X\setminus A) \supset X \setminus \text{Int}(A)$. This is equivalent to asking that $\text{cl}(X\setminus A)^c\subset \text{Int(A)}$. Now, $\text{cl}(X\setminus A)^c$ is obviously open as the complement of a closed set, and it is contained in $A$. Since $\text{Int}(A)$ is the largest open subset inside of $A$, it contains $\text{cl}(X\setminus A)^c$.